# TFS to VS Online Migration Error OH-SCM-009 item does not exist

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate a project from TFS 2010 to VS Online and am receiving the error on a specific changeset:

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. The item $/xxx/xxx/xxx.xml does not exist at the specified version or you do not have permission to access it.

The changeset in question is listed as pending for retry, but the migration does not continue and eventually stops. I noticed in VS online that the project has been migrated up through the previous changeset. The file in question is in fact missing, along with a few others. I added the missing files manually to VS online and tried to continue the migration, hoping it would then find the file and continue, but the migration simply waited a few minutes and then stopped.

I really need to migrate this project, and I am hoping not to lose all of my change history, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Other notes:

1. In the changeset that failed, there are some folders that were renamed, although the files are already missing from the previous changeset that had no renaming.
2. The migration took very long, 8-9 hours. I don't mind rerunning it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we'll need the version of the Utility that you are running. You can find the exact version by clicking on the About button in the Utility.

Secondly, could you look into your VSO (the target system) for the affected file (as shown in the error message) and compare that file's previous changesets in Source (TFS) with the Target (VSO) and you'll find a changeset (before the current one) where the ChangeType is a mismatch, thus leading to this cascading error.

If you pass the relevant information to us. We would be able to debug this on our end and provide you with the solution
It would also help us if you send the logs located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs directory.

Regards,
OpsHub Support

Comment: Thanks you. The OpsHub version used was 1.0.1.005, although I upgraded to 1.0.1.006 and tried to restart the migration after adding the missing files manually, with no luck. I sent an email to ovsmu@opshub.com containing the logs plus a Word document detailing a changeset mismatch that I discovered. Please let me know if there is a different email address.

Comment: Requested information sent on 9/15 but have not received a reply. OpsHub support, please acknowledge if you have received my information and advise next steps. Regards, TSBob.

Comment: I am having the same issue; will send my logs in an email now.

Comment: I don't want to create a separate question since it appears to the be same issue as this one. I sent the logs to ovsmu@opshub.com; let me know if I should open a separate inquiry. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gendolkari. You need not open a separate thread. Your logs have been received.